# How can i send value attribute with Html tags to server?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have a input tag with the following value attribute.It works fine and on server side i can get value=Hello

`<input type="hidden" id="Comments" name="Comments" value="Hello">`

Similarly i am trying this, i want the value along with Html tags.But this doesn't work. Here is what i mean.[ClickOnSubmitButton](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_value)

`<input type="hidden" id="Comments" name="Comments" value="<p>Hello<p><h1>Hi<h1>">`

I want to store value along with Html tags to the database to save the formatting and display back in the view.How can i achieve this?
How can i send value field with Html tags to server ? Thanks.

Comment: As @VicJordan mentioned. Or just escape all HTML elements in your value. Use [`escape()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) and [`unescape()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp).

Comment: @VicJordan Thank you ! It helped.

Comment: @Alex escape() and unescape()  is deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5. So encodeURI() and decode solved my problem.

Comment: Good to know. Glad to be any help.